# How to compute $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(2\sqrt{x^2-4}-2x+1\right)$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have a limit that I don't know how to compute: $$ \lim _{x\to \infty }\left(2\sqrt{x^2-4}-2x+1\right) $$
What I've tried : $$ \lim _{x\to \infty }\left(2\sqrt{x^2-4}-2x+1\right) = \lim _{x\to \infty }\left(x\left(2\sqrt{1-\frac{4}{x^2}}-2+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right) = \lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{\left(2\sqrt{1-\frac{4}{x^2}}-2+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{'}}{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{'}}\right) = \lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{4}{x^2}}}+-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\right) = \lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\left(-\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{4}{x^2}}}+1\right)\right) = -\infty $$ But the real answer is $1$. Where am I wrong? Thanks for any response.

Comment: You can't use L'Hopital here: numerator does not approach to $0$!

Comment: @Crostul yes... you're right... i did a mistake there

Comment: You have made a mistake in the derivative of $2\sqrt{1-\frac{4}{x^2}}$. This derivative is $$\frac{8}{x^3\sqrt{1-\frac{4}{x^2}}}$$

Comment: I am maybe wrong but I think the numerator approachs $0$. Anyway try again L'Hôpital to see what happen.

Comment: Yes, you have the limit $1$ to the first  L'Hôpital because you get a fraction of the form $$\frac {0+A}{A}$$

Comment: @Piquito You're right... thanks for the help :)

Comment: @T4yl0r: You are welcome. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\sqrt{x^2-4}-x=\frac{x^2-4-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-4}+x}=\frac{-4}{\sqrt{x^2-4}+x}$ tends to $0$ when x tends to infinity, we have $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{x^2-4}-x+1=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{-4}{\sqrt{x^2-4}+x}+1=0+1=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

As usual, when you have an indetermination of the type $\infty -\infty $ with a square root, then use the fact that 
$$\sqrt a-\sqrt b=(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt b)\cdot \frac{\sqrt a+\sqrt b}{\sqrt a+\sqrt b}=\frac{a-b}{\sqrt a+\sqrt b}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $1/x=h$

$$\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{2\sqrt{1-h^2}-2+h}h$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{4(1-h^2)-(2-h)^2}h\cdot\dfrac1{\lim_{h\to0^+}\{2\sqrt{1-h^2}+2-h\}}=?$$

Answer (score -2):

**Hint** $2\sqrt{x^2 - 4} \to 2\sqrt{x^2} \to 2x$ as $x \to \infty$, simplifying your expression $\underbrace{2\sqrt{x^2 - 4}}_{\to 2x} - 2x + 1$ to...?

Comment: This doesn't work. Using the fact that $$a(x)-b(x)=b(x)g(x)-b(x)=b(x)(g(x)-1)$$ where $b(x)\to \infty $ and $g(x)\to 1$ doesn't erase the indetermination.