# Limit $\lim_{x\to+\infty }\sqrt{x^{2}+x}-x=\frac{1}{2}$ difference between $+\infty$ $-\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, radicals

Someone can clarify a doubt risen solving a limit, please.
I know
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty }\sqrt{x^{2}+x}-x=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty }\sqrt{x^{2}+x}-x=-\infty $$
Solving the first one

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty }\sqrt{x^{2}+x}-x\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}+x}+x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+x}+x}$$
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty }\frac{x^{2}+x-x^{2}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+x}+x}$$
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty }\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}+1}=\frac{1}{2}$$
However doing the same steps, algebraically allowed, I obtein
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty }\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}+1}=\frac{1}{2}$$ WRONG
Where is the mistake?
In the second case there is some step unallowed?
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871649/how-to-find-all-answers-for-these-limits  OR http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1860197/limit-of-x-frac32-sqrtx2-2-sqrtx1-sqrtx-x-to-infty   OR http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848609/how-to-compute-lim-x-to-infty-left2-sqrtx2-4-2x1-right/1848614#1848614

Answer (score 6):

**HINT:**

$$\sqrt{x^2+x}=|x|\sqrt{1+\frac1x}\ne x\sqrt{1+\frac1x}$$

when $x<0$

**SPOILER ALERT:**  Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution.

> Note that we have $$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+x}+x}&=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{x}{|x|\sqrt{1+\frac1x}+x}\\\\&=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{x}{|x|\left(1+\frac{1}{2x}+O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)+x}\\\\&=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{2x^2}{|x|+O\left(1\right)}\\\\&=+\infty\end{align}$$

Answer (score 5):

$\sqrt {x ^2} = |{x}| \neq x $

Comment: sorry, when I started writing this your comment was not yet there. 
I agree that there is no difference, yours is better because it is more detailed. should I delete my comment?

Comment: Paul, no worry.  That has happened to me also (i.e., I've posted a solution without noticing that a similar one was previously posted).  -Mark